# Reading Cookie from a different domain?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Can javascript read a cookie from a different domain?\

If i set a cookie in one domain say www.domain1.com. Can i read that cookie from a different domain www.domain2.com?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the `document.cookie` property only gives you access to the cookies relevant to that page. Being able to read other cookies would be a fairly significant security issue.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Browsers specifically only give the current domain the cookies for that domain. This is a security feature.

You can even further specify where on your site this cookie is able to be accessed by adding a path.