# How can we use cookies to pass data from an external web site into our application in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can we use cookies to pass data from an external web site into our application in Angular JS

Comment: why do you want to use cookies?

Comment: I am searching for any suitable way to pass the data from an external web site to an angular js application. Can you tell me what is the best way to do it?

Comment: The easiest way (if it's a limited amount of data) is to pass it via the URL with a query parameter. You can even encode a JSON object in it if you want. You'd have access to it via the `$location` service in AngularJS

Comment: In my case the data is not limited that's why I was searching for some other options like cookies.

Comment: If the data is not limited I would expose it through a RESTful web service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this because you cannot get cookies of another domain. See [Reading Cookie from a different domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955183/reading-cookie-from-a-different-domain)

If you want to read cookies of your own domain you can use [the `$cookies` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

```
var favoriteCookie = $cookies.myFavorite;
```

NB: Don't forget to add `$cookies` to your controller / service method parameters (so it can be injected)

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.How can we do it if both the websites are in the same domain?

Comment: Hi Piter, so now as per my understanding somebody from the parent website has to write the cookies and that cookies will be available to us in our application(target website) and we can read through angularjs $cookies?

Comment: Are the parent site and the target site in the same domain?

Comment: yes both are in the same domain.